# How can I remove null values from output?

Tags: ansible

I am trying to fetch only specific information from the output. But I get `null` values (could be because of the irrelevant lines in the output). How can I remove these `null` values from the output?

Original output from device:

```
(wc1) *#show ap database long

AP Database
-----------
Name                Group         AP Type  IP Address    Status              Flags  Switch IP   Standby IP  Wired MAC Address  Serial #    Port  FQLN  Outer IP  User
----                -----         -------  ----------    ------              -----  ---------   ----------  -----------------  --------    ----  ----  --------  ----
AP1                 INDOOR        325      192.13.7.36   Up 67d:10h:43m:3s   2Sr    192.13.7.9  192.13.7.8  80:8c:c7:ed:fe:42  CNFZHN415M  N/A   N/A   N/A       
AP2                 INDOOR        325      192.13.7.36   Up 67d:10h:43m:3s   2Sr    192.13.7.9  192.13.7.8  80:7c:c0:ed:fe:33  CNFZHN452M  N/A   N/A   N/A    
AP3                 INDOOR        325      192.13.7.36   Up 67d:10h:43m:3s   2Sr    192.13.7.9  192.13.7.8  80:6c:c9:ed:fe:45  CNFZHN453M  N/A   N/A   N/A    
AP4                 INDOOR        325      192.13.7.36   Up 67d:10h:43m:3s   2Sr    192.13.7.9  192.13.7.8  80:5c:c8:ed:fe:67  CNFZHN454M  N/A   N/A   N/A
```

Output I see when I run script:

```
ok: [wc2] => (item=AP1_renamed  AIR_MONITOR   225      192.10.108.14  Up 96d:16h:0m:20s    2      192.10.108.4  0.0.0.0     60:f3:e6:d6:9e:06  CZ0825446   N/A   N/A   N/A       ) => {
    "ansible_facts": {
        "ap_mac_addresses": [
            null,
            null,
            null,
            null,
            "20:a6:3d:cc:93:1c",
            "20:a6:cd:dc:93:2e",
            "20:a6:3d:cc:03:3a",
            "20:a6:3d:cc:94:c6",
            "b0:b8:37:cd:3b:ea",
            "94:b4:3f:c7:2e:40",
            "94:b4:3f:c7:1e:4e",
            "94:b4:3f:c7:1d:20",
            "94:b4:3f:c7:2d:9c",
            "94:b4:2f:c7:3d:92",
            "94:b4:2f:c7:4d:9a",
            "04:bd:28:ca:52:3c",
            "94:b4:2f:c7:6d:b4",
            "94:b4:2f:c7:7d:06",
            "94:b4:0f:c7:8d:96",
            "94:b4:2f:c7:9c:e6",
            "40:e3:e6:c6:16:c0",
            "40:e3:e6:c6:22:4a",
            "40:e3:e6:c6:3e:c6"
        ]
    },
    "ansible_loop_var": "item",
    "changed": false,
    "item": "AP1_renamed  MONITOR   225      192.10.108.14  Up 96d:16h:0m:20s    2      192.10.108.4  0.0.0.0     60:f3:e6:d6:9e:06  CZ0825446   N/A   N/A   N/A       "
}
```

Script I wrote:

```yaml
---

- name: collect AP and wlc database and export to a csv file
  hosts: wlc
  gather_facts: no
  vars:
   ansible_connection: network_cli
   ansible_network_os: aruba
   
  tasks:

  - name: show AP inventory
    cli_command:
      command: "show ap database long"
    register: ap_database


  - name: Extract AP mac addresses
    set_fact:
      ap_mac_addresses: '{{ ap_mac_addresses | default ([]) + ([item |string | regex_search("([0-9A-Fa-f]{2}[:-]){5}([0-9A-Fa-f]{2})")]) }}'
       # ap_mac_addresses: '{{ ap_mac_addresses | default([]) + ([item | string | split()    
    with_items: "{{ap_database.stdout_lines}}"


  - name: print AP mac address output
    debug:
      msg: "{{ item }}"
    with_items: "{{ [] }}"

  - name: print not nulls
    debug: 
      msg: "{{ ap_mac_addresses | reject(none) | list }}"
```

Answer (score 1):

[*select*](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/latest/templates/#jinja-filters.select) values. The declaration below gives what you want

```yaml
  ap_mac_addresses_select: "{{ ap_mac_addresses|select() }}"
```

Answer (score 1):

---

*Forenote: you can drop the `list` filter in such expressions since ansible 2.10. As the oldest currently maintained ansible-core version is 2.12, and since the 2.9 version where it was still mandatory was deprecated more than 2 years ago, I guess we can lower the expression verbosity without any harm*

---

Given your above example, the correct expression to get what you expect out of your list is:

```yaml
  - name: print not nulls
    ansible.builtin.debug: 
      msg: "{{ ap_mac_addresses | select() }}"
```

Meanwhile, building up such a list with a loop in a task using `set_fact` is an overkill in this situation. You can get the correct result with a single jinja2 expression which will do the entire job without having to launch a task. So you can basically shorten your playbook to the following:

```yaml
---

- name: Collect AP and wlc database and export to a csv file
  hosts: wlc
  gather_facts: no
  vars:
    ansible_connection: network_cli
    ansible_network_os: aruba
   
    search_re: ([0-9A-Fa-f]{2}[:-]){5}([0-9A-Fa-f]{2})
    # _Note_ the below var will only return a value when called
    # after registering `ap_database`. The default value (i.e. empty list)
    # is here to avoid undefined var errors. Calling before registering
    # will return an empty list.
    ap_mac_addresses: >-
      {{
        ap_database.stdout | d([])
        | map('regex_search', search_re) | select()
      }}
   
   
  tasks:

  - name: Show AP inventory
    ansible.netcommon.cli_command:
      command: "show ap database long"
    register: ap_database

  - name: Show list of mac addresses
    ansible.builtin.debug: 
      var: ap_mac_addresses
```

Answer (score -2):

adding below task to remove the null value (that was because of blank lines)  after getting the output fixed the issue.

[image]

Comment: Please [edit] to paste the text used in the image into your answer so that it can be read on all devices, edited, copied as text, and found through search. As it stands now, your image makes it hard to view and use your answer. See the [formatting documentation](/editing-help) for tips to make your text appear nicely without resorting to images.